# Cannot call a fn<T: X> from an impl<T: X> because X is not satisfied for T

Tags: rust, traits

I have a trait `RawFd` that is implemented for each type that satisfies special requirements.

Now I have a function that accepts any type that implements `RawFd`. And I have a trait with an implementation for each `T` that implements `RawFd`.

However I cannot call my function from my trait even if `T` implements `RawFd`:

```
pub trait RawFd {
    fn raw_fd(&self) -> u64;
}

#[cfg(unix)]
impl<T: std::os::unix::io::AsRawFd> RawFd for T {
    fn raw_fd(&self) -> u64 { self.as_raw_fd() as u64 }
}

#[cfg(windows)]
impl<T: std::os::windows::io::AsRawSocket> RawFd for T {
    fn raw_fd(&self) -> u64 { self.as_raw_socket() as u64 }
} 

fn print_fd<T: RawFd>(p: T) {
    println!("{}", p.raw_fd());
}

trait Printable {
    fn print(&self);
}

impl<T: RawFd> Printable for T {
    fn print(&self) {
        print_fd(self);
    }
}
```

What is my mistake here and how can I solve it.

(Link to [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=92d30ba23735868a5e50d2bbd264c925&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

Comment: The code you listed in the playground link, can you update it here?

Comment: Sry; the playground was outdated. I updated it 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect to use `print_fd()` with a reference you must do this:

```
fn print_fd(p: &impl RawFd) {
    println!("{}", p.raw_fd());
}
```

or

```
fn print_fd<T: RawFd>(p: &T) {
    println!("{}", p.raw_fd());
}
```

---

Or you must take self by value:

```
impl<T: RawFd> Printable for T {
    fn print(self) {
        print_fd(self);
    }
}
```

---

Or you could use clone:

```
impl<T> Printable for T where T: Clone + RawFd {
    fn print(&self) {
        print_fd(self.clone());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shepmaster Can you show on exemple ? This is still confuse for me.

Comment: @Stargateur looks like it's not possible (or easy) to do here because there's already a blanket implementation on `T`. You could instead [specify the specific trait bound needed](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c514800b728c46e052247198cf8cf804&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)